# Api is working in postman but response always return 500 in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dio

My rest api is working successfully. When I send post request in flutter with Dio. Service always return 500 internal server error.
[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ0KG.png)

[post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFHK8.png)

[Dio Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTE16.png)

Comment: code screenshot is not a right way. you need to put the code here. then other developers can easily check and find out the solution.

Comment: Can you add _apinetwork.post method here please?

Comment: @kaushikChandru it is the method of Dio.

Answer (score 0):

To create a form data use this

```
var formData = FormData.fromMap({
 'user': 'username',
 'pass': 'password',
});

response = await dio.post('apiendpoint', data: formData);
```

Comment: thanks but it returns 415 Unsupported Media Type

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the content-type in your header.. based on what your remote accepts either `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` or `'application/json'`

```
var data = {"phone": mobileNumber, "password": password};
var dio = Dio();

dio.options.headers['content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

try {
  var response = await dio.post(ApiUrl.baseUrl + url, data: data);
  print(response);
} on DioError catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

Comment: Actually, when i try get request it is also returning 500.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way :

```
var formData = {
 'user': 'username',
 'pass': 'password',
};

response = await dio.post('apiendpoint', data: jsonEncode(formData));
```